# React redux - pushing new item to the state array not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm having an issue with adding a new item to the state array variable. In the "CategorySection" component I'm calling .push() to add "new_category" to the "categories" array, but nothing happens, not even an error.

As I try to create a new category by calling "handleAddCategory" which triggers a dispatch for "createCategory", I can see in the Redux DevTools that it has been added to the "item" state once I get the data back from my backend, but then when .push() is called in the "CategorySection" component, as I said before, nothing happens.

It's really weird, because I'm doing the same process in a different part of my project, and there it's working just fine. For example, I create a new Task, and when getting this created task back from my backend, I push it to the items state variable, and then the component gets re-rendered.

**Category Reducer**

```
const initialState = {
  items: [],
  item: {},
}

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case GET_CATEGORIES:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.payload
      }

    case CREATE_CATEGORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        item: action.payload
      }
    

    default:
        return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

**Category Actions**

```
export const getCategories = () => {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/get-categories/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CATEGORIES,
      payload: data
    });
  }
}

export const createCategory = (name) => {
  return async(dispatch) => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/manage-category/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'),
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({'name': name})
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    dispatch({
      type: CREATE_CATEGORY,
      payload: data
    });
  }
}
```

**CategorySection component**

Here I'm trying to call .push in the second useEffect, because sumTasks() must be called only when "categories" changes, but unfortunately it's not pushing at all...

```
import React from 'react'
import CategoryItem from './CategoryItem'
import AddPopover from '../popovers/AddPopover'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getTasks } from '../../state/action-creators/taskActions';
import { createCategory, setActiveCategory } from '../../state/action-creators/categoryActions';

const CategorySection = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const categories = useSelector((state) => state.category.items);
  const new_category = useSelector((state) => state.category.item);
  const active_category = useSelector((state) => state.category.active);

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [totalTasks, setTotalTasks] = useState(0);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  useEffect(() => {
    sumTasks();
  }, [categories])

  useEffect(() => {
    categories.push(new_category);
    
  }, [new_category])

  function sumTasks() {
    let sum = categories.reduce((total, current) => total = total + current.total_tasks, 0);
    setTotalTasks(sum);
  }

  const onCategoryClick = async (id) => {
    if(active_category != id) {
      await dispatch(setActiveCategory(id));
      await dispatch(getTasks());
    }
  }

  const single_category = categories && categories.map((category) => {
    return(
      <CategoryItem key={category.id} category={category} active_category={active_category} onCategoryClick={onCategoryClick} />
    )
  })

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
  
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const handleAddCategory = async (e, value) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13 && value != '') {
      setAnchorEl(null);
      await dispatch(createCategory(value));
    }
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="bg-dark mb-3" id="category-wrapper">
      <div className="container mt-2 mb-2">
        <div className="row">
          <span className="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div className="fs-4 text-white">
              Categories
            </div>
            <div className="category-tooltip-div" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" title="">
              <svg onClick={handleClick} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" fill="orange" id="sidebar-add-category"
                className="bi bi-plus-square rename-add-icon category-add-icon global-add-category-icon" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path
                  d="M14 1a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V2a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h12zM2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2z" />
                <path
                  d="M8 4a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3A.5.5 0 0 1 8 4z" />
              </svg>
              <AddPopover 
                open={open}
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                horizontal={30}
                onClose={handleClose}
                placeholder="Enter Category name"
                handlePressEnter={handleAddCategory}
              />
            </div>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="container" id="sidebar-categories">
        <li className={`row hovered-nav-item active-category ${active_category == -1 ? "item-selected" : ""}`}>
          <span onClick={() => onCategoryClick(-1)} className="category-link category-item fs-5 d-flex " id="sidebar-all-tasks" value="-1">
            <div className="all-tasks-text">All</div>

            {totalTasks > 0 ? (
              <div className="total-number">
                <div className="number">{totalTasks}</div>
              </div>
            ):''}

          </span>
        </li>
        <div id="categories-loop">
          {single_category}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CategorySection
```

Comment: You should not mutate the categories with push, but create an action that adds the item immutable to the array

Comment: I've looked into adding to the state array, and I posted an answer below. The thing is, I was looking at the Travis Media tutorial on redux on YT, and he used .push() to add a new post to the array and it was working...

Comment: He probably used immer in this context with the redux toolkit kit maybe? But still in an action probably?

Answer (score 3):

I've changed the CREATE_CATEGORY reducer to:

```
case CREATE_CATEGORY:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, action.payload]
      }
```